# Displaying a report returned after submitting a form in Angular 2

Tags: angular

My app will send a set of user-entered data to the server where a report is generated based on an analysis of those data and sent back to the app.

My problem is that I don't know how/where to handle/present that report. I started off thinking that the report should be passed to another view/component (in combination with a `this.router.navigate([...])`), but when I started reading about passing data between components, I got lost to the extent that I couldn't confidently describe which component was the parent and which was the child!!

So, I'm after some direction here - what technique/approach should I be taking?